# Django translation: get_language

Tags: django

I set the language with a language chooser like this:

```
def change_lang(request):
    lang_code = request.GET.get('language')
    if lang_code:
        if hasattr(request, 'session'):
            request.session['django_language'] = lang_code
        activate(lang_code)
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps('OK'),content_type=c_type)
```

The page gets reloaded and translated into the chosen language.

But when I do another request on the page i.e. to fetch more posts and I want to know the current language and I use `lang = get_language()` the language is english and not the language that was chosen before.

Thank you for any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
lang = request.session.get('django_language', 'english')
```

That code will get the `django_language` variable from the session.